# A multilinear question and its smooth version

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, multilinear-algebra

Let $E$ and $F$ be two finite  dimensional vector spaces. For every $k\in \mathbb{N}$, $E^{k}$ has a natural vector space structure and  is isomorphic to $E\otimes \mathbb{R}^{k}$, in a natural way.

We denote by $L^{k}(E)$ $\;$($\Lambda ^{k}(E^{*})$), the space of all $k$-linear maps (anti-symmetric $k$-linear maps) from $E^{k}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. We say that a linear map $T:E^{k}\to F^{k}$ is  a tensorial map(anti symmetric tensorial map) if $\forall  \alpha \in L^{k}(F)\;(\alpha \in \Lambda^{k}(F^{*}))$, $\alpha \circ T$ belongs to $L^{k}(E)(\Lambda^{k}(E^{*}))$. Clearly such maps form a semi group (with composition)  when $E=F$.

> **A Multilinear question:**  What is  a reference for classification of (the semi group of) all tensorial maps  and anti symmetric tensorial maps? Putting $E=F$, is it true to say that an antisymmetric tensorial map is  necessarilly in the form $T\otimes S$ for some linear maps $T:E \to  E$  and $S:\mathbb{R}^{k} \to \mathbb{R}^{k}$?

Now assume that $E_{1},\ldots E_{k}$, $F_{1},\ldots F_{k}$ are finite dimensional vector spaces. A tensorial linear map $T:\prod E_{i}\to \prod F_{i}$ has  a relevant definition.(simillar to the above definition). This   definition enable us to ask the following non linear question:

> **A nonlinear question:**  Put $M=\mathbb{T}^{n}$. What is  an example of  an smooth non linear  map $f$ on the $n$-torus such that  $Df_{x}:T_{x}M\to T_{f(x)} M$ is  a tensorial map for all $x\in \mathbb{T}^{n}$? By non linear map We mean" $f$ is not equal to the restriction of  a linear map on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$  which send $\mathbb{T}^{n}$ to  $\mathbb{T}^{n}$. What  obstruction would  appear in non linear case?

Comment: @HassanJolany Mr. Jolany thanks for your revision. Befor that I read and realize your tag-revision, I was removing the last part of the question and post it in a a new question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/165755/a-generalized-de-rham-cohomology?noredirect=1#comment422185_165755

Comment: @HassanJolany I am sorry for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know whether such a classification exists, but the answer to the second multilinear question is "no":

Consider the case $E=F=\mathbb{R}^2$, $k=3$, and the map $T:(a,b,a',b',a'',b'')\mapsto (a,b,a,b,b',b'')$.  This map is linear, but not of tensor form.  However, it is antisymmetric tensorial, since $\alpha\circ T=0$ for any $\alpha\in\Lambda^3(F)$.

Concerning the non-linear question: Identify $\mathbb{R}^{2n}\cong\mathbb{C}^n$ and consider the map $f:(z_1,\dots,z_n)\mapsto(z_1^2,\dots,z_n^2)$.  Each $D_xf$ is represented by a diagonal matrix, which is tensorial.

Comment: however your linear example is not a tensorial map.

Comment: Yes, but you were asking for an antisymmetric tensorial map.  According to your definition, an antisymmetric tensorial map need not be tensorial.  It just needs to preserve the set of anti-symmetric k-linear forms.

Comment: Yes you are right. thanks again for your example. Can I ask you to read the "Motivation" in the last part of my question?may you give some comment on this subject?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not an expert in deRham cohomology.

Comment: I moved the motivation part to a new question  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/165755/a-generalized-de-rham-cohomology.