# A Generalized De Rham cohomology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, lie-groups, differential-operators

**Edit** According to the comment of Alex Degtyarev, I deleted the last part of the previous version.

Let $E$ be a real vector space. The complex valued $k$- tensors on $E$ is denoted by $L_{\mathbb{C}}^{k}(E)$, that is, the space of all k-linear maps from $E^{k}$ to $\mathbb{C}$.  A  linear  map $T$ in $GL(E^{k})$  is  called  a tensorial map if $\forall \alpha \in L_{\mathbb{C}}^{k}(E)$, the composition $\alpha \circ T$ belongs to $L_{\mathbb{C}}^{k}(E)$. For  example  a  permutation in $S_{k}$ gives us  a tensorial linear map on $E^{k}$.  Let $G_{K}$ be the subgroup of $GL(E^{k})$ consists all tensorial maps in $GL(E^{k})$. There is  a natural embedding from $G_{k}$ to $G_{k+1}$ which sends $T$ to $T\oplus Id_{E}$.

Assume  that $G$ is  a  compact topological subgroup of $G_{k}$. (For example, the permutation group $S_{k}$ is  embedded in $G_{k}$.

We fix a character $\phi:G \to S^{1}$.(For example $\phi$ is the $\it{sign}$ character, when $G$ is $S_{k}$). We assume that $\mu$ is the Haar measure(ex:Counting measure for $S_{k}$). We say that $\alpha \in L_{\mathbb{C}}^{k}(E)$ is $G$ invariant if $\alpha \circ T=\phi (T) \alpha, \forall T\in  G$.(For $G=S_{k}$, this definition, gives us the definition of  ordinary "k-forms" on $E$). We denote the collection of all $G$ invariant tensors by $\tilde{\Lambda}(E^{*})$.

For two $G$-invariant tensors $\alpha$ and $\beta$ we define $\alpha \tilde{\wedge} \beta:=\int_{G} \phi(T) (\alpha \otimes \beta)\circ T$, which is a $G$-invariant tensor. This  definition is  motivated by the ordinary wedge product of ordinary "forms".

A linear  map $S$ on $E$ is called $G$-invariant if $\oplus_{i=1}^{k}  S$ commutes with all operators in $G$.(When $G=S_{k}$, all linear maps $T$ on $E$, are automatically,$G$-invariant).  Obviously the pull back of an invariant tensor, under an invariant linear map, is again an invariant tensor. Now under the following condition on a manifold $M$,we can non-linearize this process to obtain $\tilde{\Omega}^{k}(M)$,  in the same manner as the ordinary DeRham cohomology: the condition is that we have  an atlas for $M$ such that the jacobian of each transition map is  $G$ invariant.  Now a natural question is that:

> "Is there  a natural  complex of (differential) operators $\tilde{d}:\tilde{\Omega}^{k}(M) \to \tilde{\Omega}^{k+1}(M)$ ? Is it useful to  produce and study such kind of cohomology? Does such cohomology give us new information, different from information which is obtained from deRham cohomology? What is an algebraic topological version of such smooth cohomology?(motivating by the fact that singular cohomology is parallel to the DeRham cohomology). Under what conditions we have  an atlas such that the jacobian of transition maps are $G$ invariant?

**Note** Acording to the comment of Mariano I add the following example:Put $E=\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ which is identified with $\mathbb{C}^{n}$. Let $H$ be a torus in $GL(E)$ which all operators, commute with the real-Jacobian of all local holomorphic map from open sets of $\mathbb{C}^{n}\to \mathbb{C}^{n}$. Ex; $n=1$ $H=$ rotations.

Then $H^{k}=\prod_{i=1}^{k} H$ is a subgroup of $G_{k}$ and the natural embedding of $G_{k}$ into $G_{k+1}$is compatible with the natural embedding of $H^{k}$ into $H^{k+1}$ which add the identity element. Choose and fix a character $\phi$ on  $H$. Then define the character $\phi_{k}$ on $H^{k}$ with $\phi_{k}=\prod \phi$. So $\phi_{k+1}$ is an extension of $\phi_{k}$. So I think the approach of this post is applicable to holomorphic manifolds, provided we choose and fix in priori, $H$ and $\phi$ as above.

Comment: What is a $k$-tensor? Doesn't the whole group $GL$ act on the whole tensor algebra? What is this special "tensorial" condition?

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev by $k-tensor$ I mean a k-linear map from $E^{k}$ to $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev Now I realize what you mean. I just consider 0-k tensors(If i am not mistaken in terminology). so $GL(E^{k}$ does not act on it.

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev  is my question clear, now?

Comment: Yes, it's clear, but I'm not exited. Concerning your last question, as I said, any subgroup of $GL(E)$ (e.g., $O(E)$ if you want it compact) would act on any tensor power. As to the atlas, you're speaking about the "structure group reduction", which is a well developed subject.

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev  I Think there is  a misunderstanding on the notion of action: are you saying that for every $k$-linear map $\alpha:E^{k} \to \mathbb{C}$ and every arbitrary linear map $T\in GL(E^{k}$, $\alpha \circ T$ is  necessarily a $k$-linear map?(I  think it is not true). Note that my action was simply the "composition". What action you are talking about?

Comment: Unlike you, I'm speaking about $GL(E)$, not $GL(E^k)$. All I know is that $T^*$ is a functor (as so are $\otimes$ and $\operatorname{Hom}$), and the action is obvious.

Comment: Thank you. so you introduce the product $G=\prod_{i=1}^{k} O(E)$ as an example which I was searching for.  So we choose "Determinant" as a real valued character(1,-1). Does this  situation leads to  a nontrivial cohomology? What would be  a (differential) operator $\tilde{d}$? Is "determinant" the only possible character?

Comment: Your G is contained in one G_k, and you arenviewing it as acting on the higher than kth tensors by the inclusion of G_k into G_{k+1} that you mention. First, this does not tell us how G acts on *lower* tensors, and second if you do this with S_k you certainly do not get the usual de Rham complex!

Comment: With $G=\prod O(E)$ as in your last comment, the wedge of any two vectors is zero, since the average of any vector over $SO(E)$ is zero. This sort of kills any chance of defining $\tilde d$ in the usual way, by its action on 0-forms and then extending by wedge products. Also, I'm not sure your definition of invariant extends the classical case-- for example $e_1\wedge e_2$ is fixed by $(3,4)$, hence not invariant in your sense. I think you mean the basis elements of $\Lambda^k$ should be $k$-fold wedge products.

Comment: @BrendanMurphy Thanks for your comment. First, I work with covectors not vectors. second put $E=\mathbb{R}$. $k=2$. $G=O(\mathbb{R})\times O(\mathbb{R})$, the character $\phi=Det$. Then we have $dx\tilde{\wedge} dx=4 dx\otimes dx$, a non zero tensor. In fact I am introducing a new wedge product. For more detail, please read my comment as a response to Mariano's comment(Which I will wrote up to 30 minute.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez thank you for your attention on my post. I  think there is an interesting case which my approach works, well. Put $E=\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. Identify $E$ with $\mathbb{C}^{n}$. Let $H$ be a torus in $GL(E)$ with the property that for every holomorphic map $f: U \to \mathbb{C}^n$, $U\subset \mathbb{C}^n$, all $T\in H$ commutes with $J(f)_{x}$ as a real linear map on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. Ex: for $n=1$ this Torus is the group of rotations.(I do not know what is the maximal dimension for such torus?). Choose and fix a character $\phi$ for $H$. I continue in the next comment

Comment: My two previous comments can not be read, well. i can not delete or revised them. so i summarize both comments in the following. @BrendanMurphy Put $E=\mathbb{R}$, $k=2$ $G=\prod O(\mathbb{R})$. Then $dx \tilde{\wedge} dx =4 dx \otimes dx$, a non zero tensor.

Comment: @AliTaghavi I added some dollar signs to your comments.

Comment: @S.Carnahan Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @AliTaghavi Well in the case $E=R^1$, $SO(E)$ is the identity group, but in the case $E=R^2$, $dx\tilde\wedge dx$ is composed of four terms like $\int_{\rho_1\in SO(2)}\int_{\rho_2\in SO(2)}d(\rho_1 x)\otimes d(\rho_2 x)$, and each integral is zero since a vector gets averaged over $SO(2)$ before it gets plugged in to $dx$.

Comment: @BrendanMurphy Thanks for your interesting comment. I think you use 'the separation variable" in your computation.Yes?This computation is valid because of the special form of $G$:it is a diagonal product. This is a motivation to consider some groups which is not in the product form(to avoid the triviality). however in the case you considered(with $G=SO(E) $  not $O(E)$, we have $\alpha \tilde{\wedge} \alpha \neq 0$ when $\alpha= dx \otimes dx$. So it is not true that our (averaging) wedge product is always zero..

Comment: @AliTaghavi Yes, the product group lets you use Fubini's theorem to compute the integral. If $G=O(E)$ there are 4 terms instead of 1 because $O(E)$ is a union of two cosets of $SO(E)$. Each integral is zero if $E$ has dimension greater than 1. I will compute one integral explicitly: let $\alpha(x,y)=x$ and let $\beta(x,y)=x$. Then $$\alpha\tilde\wedge\beta((x,y),(u,v))=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}(x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta)(u\cos\phi+v\sin\phi)d\theta  d\phi =0.$$

Comment: @BrendanMurphy yes, I see. thank you.

Comment: Another way to see this is through the [mean ergodic theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_theory#Mean_ergodic_theorem). You are considering unitary operators acting on the Hilbert space of $k$-forms, so averaging over any one parameter group will result in a projection on to the fixed points of that group---namely $L_{\mathbb{C}}^k(E)$. If you have non-trivial action on the individual components, it seems like it will just reduce you to a smaller dimension base space (at least looking at $k=1$); thus like you mentioned it seems that the groups that mix are the interesting ones.